# How to fix 'DSN 'plesk' is invalid' error during Plesk installation

Tags: plesk

I tried to intall plesk using a remote database but im getting this problem

This is the error I got:

`` `Installing packages ``

`**** Product prep-install started.`
`Create user 'psaadm' and group 'psaadm'`
`Group 'psaadm' already exists`
`Checking for the user 'psaadm'...`
`User 'psaadm' already exists`
`Create group 'swkey-data'`
`Group 'swkey-data' already exists`
`Trying to add supplementary group 'swkey-data' for user 'psaadm'...  already there`
`Create group 'psaserv'`
`Group 'psaserv' already exists`
`Trying to add supplementary group 'psaserv' for user 'psaadm'...  already there`
`Create group 'psacln'`
`Group 'psacln' already exists`
`Trying to got legacy variables... done`
`Trying to save legacy variables... done`

`DSN 'plesk' is invalid: 'username' is not specified`

`*****  problem report *****`
`DSN 'plesk' is invalid: 'username' is not specified`

`Launching component and product checkers...`
`Downloading file report-update: 0%`
`Downloading file report-update: 100% was finished.`
`Downloading file pool/PSA_18.0.52_11753/examiners/py_launcher.sh: 0%`
`Downloading file pool/PSA_18.0.52_11753/examiners/py_launcher.sh: 100% was finished.`
`Downloading file pool/PSA_18.0.52_11753/examiners/save-installation-info.php: 0%`
`Downloading file pool/PSA_18.0.52_11753/examiners/save-installation-info.php: 100% was finished.`
`Downloading file pool/PSA_18.0.52_11753/examiners/php_launcher.sh: 0%`
`Downloading file pool/PSA_18.0.52_11753/examiners/php_launcher.sh: 100% was finished.`
`Components and product check results:`
`Store installation info`

`ERROR: An error occurred during performing of installation PREP actions (see log for details). Installation was rolled back.`
`Warning! Not all packages were installed.`
`Please check if your system services are operable.`
`Please resolve this issue and try to install the packages again.`
``` Visit ``https://support.plesk.com/`` to search for a solution. ```

I'm running this command:

`PLESK_DB_DSN=mysql://plesk1:@W62dv8ui@44.214.48.106/host1_psa \ PLESK_DB_APSC_DSN=mysql://apsc1:@W62dv8ui@44.214.48.106/host1_apsc \ PLESK_DB_ROUNDCUBE_DSN=mysql://mail1:@W62dv8ui@44.214.48.106/host1_roundcubemail \ ./plesk-installer --select-product-id plesk --select-release-latest --installation-type Recommended`

And I followed this documentation: https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/obsidian/deployment-guide/plesk-for-linux-plesk-installation-without-the-local-database.79703/